# Is this safe against "spam" and "automation bots"?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, security

I have a classifieds website, and I just asked a question regarding if I need to use captcha or not whenever users post a new classified etc.

Some places on my website (like contact forms) do need some sort of authentication (captcha etc...).

But I don't know whether I need one when posting a new classified, so I turn to you guys to decide.

Here is the procedure today:

- User clicks on "new classified".
- User fills out a form containing alot of inputs/selects etc. The selects are javascript populated btw, if that makes any difference.
- Users then click "Preview Classified" button.
- Next is the "Preview" page, where users see what their classified would look like.
- Here, all the form information from the first page is stored in SESSION variables.
- If the user is satisfied, then they have to choose a password. This is done by filling out another small form in the "Preview" page at the bottom, with two inputs, "Password" and "Verify Password". This password will later be used to delete the classified, edit it etc.
- When the password is entered and validated with Javascript (not empty, no special chars etc) then users may press the "Insert Classified" button.
- The "Preview" page is submitted to a "insert_ad_into_database.php" page.
- Remember setting all information into SESSION variables, well this page uses those variables to insert them into the databases (MySql and Solr indices).
- If the classified got inserted, a "Success" text is echoed, otherwise "ERROR" is echoed.

Do you think I need captcha on this, as it actually is two forms which needs to be filled out? (classified form and password form)

Thanks

Comment: Not directly related: No special characters in password? Doesn't sound good...

Comment: I mean "really special", not the standard special characters. examples are accent letters, as well as quotes or double-quotes etc

Comment: You should validate all of the inputs on the server as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already gave my full answer to this in your other question (let the principle of "least barrier to entry" guide you), but I'll give a recap summary here:

- No, this is not safe from spam bots (but it would require a fairly sophisticated spam bot to get through this -- a standard-issue "post something to a form" spambot will break down here).
- But you also shouldn't include a captcha until you've seen an actual problem with spam.

Spam bots (especially sophisticated ones) are way less common than you might think, and captchas hurt new user acquisition way more than you might think. The trade-off is easily in the direction of no captcha.

Comment: I would still add a little barrier by limiting the number of "classifieds" that a user can submit per minute.

Comment: @ZeissS, yeah, I said more about rate limiting requests in the other question.